# Yii2 How to reference the public main.php file on the server

Tags: php, yii2, share

I used  yii2 framework  to do three sites, the three sites belonging to different servers, their layouts / main.php exactly the same, how to make these three different domain name website share this main.php?For example, a company's community and forums, as well as the official website are exactly the same layout file, which means that the three sites of the header and footer is the
same, according to my current practice, the three sites are writing this layout File and inside the style and pictures, then the problem occurs, if you want to change the footer and the title html, css, js or pictures, there will be three sites together, this is too much trouble. My current idea is to put the main.php file into one of the site's root directory, and then three sites in the frontend / layouts / main.php reference to the main.php inside the code, but how to do pictures and Style, please Experts advise?

Answer (score 0):

You can include remote files using the [allow_url_include](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) directive, but this is a really bad idea because of the security risks.

In my opinion the way to go is to build a module with your layout-related files and then update it in the applications, using composer (or any other tool) when you make changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scaffolding like advanced  template where different application (eg: backend and frontend)  share common code .. Yii 2 Advanced Project Template is a skeleton Yii 2 application best for developing complex Web applications with multiple tiers.

By default the advanced template includes three tiers: front end, back end, and console, each of which is a separate Yii application. front end and back end  app share common namespace for models and config and you can extend for place a common layout   or other application based on the same guidelines

This template is also  designed to work in a team development environment. It supports deploying the application in different environments.

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md